# SQLite Time of Day in SELECT Query

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, timestamp

I am trying to write a SELECT query that will select data from a number of tables in a database I am looking at. I can get all the data fine. however, I am having trouble parsing a column named time_of_day.

The date is stored in a column called julian_day, which I can parse easily by using:

```
SELECT strftime("%d/%m/%Y", julian_day) FROM reminder
```

The values for time_of_day are:

32400000

72000000

54600000

The last one I know should represent the time 15:10. However, if I do:

```
SELECT time(54600000)
```

I get 12:00:00; I get this no matter which value I substitute.

Obviously I am missing something... but I have searched and searched and tried everything I can thin of and I cant seem to get it working.

Are these timestamps what I think they are or are they something completely different?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know how I missed this :)

It is the number of milliseconds in the day. So the following query will convert it:

```
SELECT strftime("%H:%M:%S", 54600000/1000, "UNIXEPOCH")
```

or using the table name

```
SELECT strftime("%H:%M:%S", time_of_day/1000, "UNIXEPOCH") FROM reminder
```

Comment: Was the column actually called "julian_day"?

Comment: Sorry if my original post was confusing. There were two columns. One called julian_day which i had no problems with and another called time_of_day which I had problems with but realised it is just the number of milliseconds in the day.

Comment: I agree... but I was stuck and thinking I just couldn't do it... but I guess I am just more tired than I realise :)